# 'Flat' colour window borders in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I'm trying to get solid colour window borders in Windows 7. I've switched off transparency in the 'Window color and appearance' settings and selected a colour but I still get the 'shiny window' look superimposed on the colour:

[image: Window border with 'shiny' look]

What I'm after is this:

[image: Window border without 'shiny' look]

Windows seems to overlay the same image that you get when you hover the mouse in the 'Show Desktop' area in the bottom right of the screen:

[image: 'Shiny' overlay]

Is it possible to remove this?

Comment: Most likely the only way is to disable aero, then you are stuck with the horrid basic theme. Seems we all miss some of the tweak features XP had. I ran across an article on how to tweak the basic theme for more colors. http://windows7center.com/forums/useful-guides/1878-how-change-colour-windows-7-basic.html

Answer (score 1):

In the registry, go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM`

Set `ColorizationGlassReflectionIntensity` to 0

Restart the Desktop Window Manager Session Manager service

Answer (score 0):

There's a possibility to disable the Show Desktop's Peek, move your mouse to the Show Desktop there and right click it, there should be a tick with the "Peek", just untick it?

I'm not sure if that can help you to solve your problem, because mine was Windows 7 Home Basic. Doesn't have the "Peek" choice on "Show Desktop".